# Is there any way to remove scrollbar from every browser for my website?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

So I was building my portfolio using *React.js* and I'm stuck on removing the scrollbar. I've tried `overflow: hidden` for the parent and `overflow: scroll` for the child div respectively but its not working and I've tried *Fullpage.js* that to doesn't work for me.

I want to completely remove the scrollbar from the whole website. Could you please help me? This is my *App.js*

~ *This is a reference site*: http://kuon.space/

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import Home from "../home/Home";
import About from "../about/About";
import Skill from "../skill/Skill";
import Project from "../project/Project";
import Contact from "../contact/Contact";
import ThemeContext from "../../common/ThemeContext";

function App() {
    const [theme, setState] = useState('darks')
    const themeStyle = {
        dark:{
            background: '#121212',
            primary: '#DADADA',
            secondary: "#A13251"
        },
        light:{
            background: '#E1E1E1',
            primary: '#333333',
            secondary: '#008F96'
        }
    }
    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={
            theme==='light'?
            themeStyle.light:
            themeStyle.dark
            }>
            <Home />
            <About />
            <Skill />
            <Project />
            <Contact />
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't see a scrollbar in safari. But incidentally, it is obnoxious to pollute the user's history while they scroll...if someone scrolls more than one or two frames, using the back button to leave your site is out of the question.

Comment: That's not my site. I just gave the link as a reference. @M-N

Comment: please give us the your site code!

Comment: Why don't you check how your reference site is implementing it? You can always debug and see it for yourself?

Comment: @Prajwal ~ I've tried that, he is using FullPage.js which is not working for my scenario.

Comment: @BloodyLogic ~ The whole code?

Comment: upload your code to online editor like codepen..!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380636/reactjs-way-of-hide-sidebar-in-layout

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. The reason there is no scroll bar is because there is only ever one page's worth of html rendered at a time, and it is rendered at height 100%. There is no content off screen to scroll to, and when you try to scroll, the site intercepts the scroll event and prevents the default scrolling action (which would trigger the need for a scrollbar), handling it by rendering a whole new page that also takes up 100% height.

Comment: @BloodyLogic ~ that's not my website brother

Comment: @M-N ~ Yeah bro! I knew that from before, working on some other stuff now. 'll update this thread as soon as I finish it.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the scrollbars with css. But doesn't work with mobile browsers.

```
.hide-scrollbar {
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox 64 */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Internet Explorer 11 */
}
.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar { /** WebKit */
  display: none;
}
```

Another solution is

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    width: 0 !important 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```css
html{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33713067)